# Raise maximum connection limit for Internet Sharing?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, internet-sharing

I’m using Internet Sharing (USB 10/100/1000 LAN → Wi-Fi) to give a tech demo of a web site, running locally on my machine, to multiple phones.

I want to connect 15 phones to the shared network, but upon connecting the 6<sup>th</sup> phone, the phone reported “Access point temporarily full”.

**Is there a way to configure how many devices can connect to Internet Sharing?** I’m fine with delving into the Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no setting to configure the maximum number of stations that can connect to the access point at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The limit seems to be hard-coded into macOS and cannot be modified by setting properties or similar.

However, if it is an option to use additional hardware, you may put a router in between. That way, only the router would connect via Internet sharing, while the other devices would connect to the router.

Comment: This. I'd suggest a little palm-sized "travel router" such as the nifty models offered by GL.iNet (gl-inet.com).